# boost::split leaves empty tokens at the beginning and end of string - is this desired behaviour?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, split

Since I couldn't find anything on this in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo.html), I thought I ask it here. I  have the following program (C++11):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main () {
    string tmp = " #tag #tag1#tag2  #tag3 ####tag4   ";
    list<iterator_range<string::iterator> > matches;
    split( matches, tmp, is_any_of("\t #"), token_compress_on );

    for( auto match: matches ) {
            cout << "'" << match << "'\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
''
'tag'
'tag1'
'tag2'
'tag3'
'tag4'
''
```

I would have thought that the `token_compress_on` option removes all empty tokens. 
The solution is, for example, to use `boost::trim_if`. Nevertheless I was wondering if this is the desired behaviour of boost::split, and why this is happening?

(g++ 4.6.3, boost 1.48)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior is intentional, because you could recreate the string (complete with starting and trailing spaces) from the split version. Boost doesn't know if that whitespace is significant or not to you (it might be, as some file formats, for example, might force leading spaces/specific space counts).

You should `trim_if` or `trim` as you are if you do need to remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the point, but how can I recreate " #tag #tag1#tag2  #tag3 ####tag4   " from the tokens "", "tag", "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", ""?

Comment: @fdlm That would be specific to the format of your string. The behavior of `boost::split` is pretty general, but for some users, they might care about preserving trailing/leading characters that would otherwise be removed by splitting on them. Basically if you need those characters gone, you need to be explicit and compose functions together that do what you expect.

Answer (score 8):

If `eCompress` argument is set to `token_compress_on`, adjacent separators are merged together. Otherwise, every two separators delimit a token.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html)

It does not remove the tokens only merges them.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::split` always returns `n + 1` tokens where `n` is number of separators in the input string. So don't be surprised when it returns 1 token when you pass it an empty string.

The rationale behind it is quite simple. Imagine that you are parsing a CSV file. You need to get the exactly same number of elements regardless whether the last token is empty or not.

It is much easier to remove the empty tokens than to guess whether they were supposed to be in the result or not. [Credit](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Result-of-boost-split-against-empty-string-changed-in-post-1-45-release-tp4631147p4631393.html)

This behaviour is similar to python

```
>>> len("".split(','))
1
```