# How to use boost split to split a string and ignore empty values?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, split

I am using boost::split to parse a data file. The data file contains lines such as the following.

data.txt

```
1:1~15  ASTKGPSVFPLAPSS SVFPLAPSS   -12.6   98.3
```

The white space between the items are tabs. The code I have to split the above line is as follows.

```
std::string buf;
/*Assign the line from the file to buf*/
std::vector<std::string> dataLine;
boost::split( dataLine, buf , boost::is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);       //Split data line
cout << dataLine.size() << endl;
```

For the above line of code I should get a print out of 5, but I get 6. I have tried to read through the documentation and this solution seems as though it should do what I want, clearly I am missing something. Thanks!

Edit:
Running a forloop as follows  on dataLine you get the following.

```
cout << "****" << endl;
for(int i = 0 ; i < dataLine.size() ; i ++) cout << dataLine[i] << endl;
cout << "****" << endl;


****
1:1~15
ASTKGPSVFPLAPSS
SVFPLAPSS
-12.6
98.3

****
```

Comment: what are the values stored in dataLine?

Comment: [I get 5](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1KMXAm$1), your `buf` contains something else.

Comment: Perhaps it did not copy properly into this page your copied it incorrectly into a test code. Let me see about making sure it copies correctly.

Comment: If you `buf` contains a space at the end, [I get the same results](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1KMXAm$5).

Comment: It contains a tab at the end. I would like to have that last tab ignored. I thought that was what token_compress_on was for. Is there a way to get the split function to ignore this last item?

Comment: Would it be insufficient to just use a `boost::algorithm::trim` variant?

Comment: I suppose not. But this only trims a string of leading and trailing whitespace(and not just the space character) correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though "adjacent separators are merged together", it seems like the trailing delimeters make the problem, since even when they are treated as one, it still *is* one delimeter.

So your problem cannot be solved with `split()` alone. But luckily Boost String Algo has [`trim()` and `trim_if()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp163415616), which strip whitespace or delimeters from beginning and end of a string. So just call `trim()` on buf, like this:

```
std::string buf = "1:1~15  ASTKGPSVFPLAPSS SVFPLAPSS   -12.6   98.3    ";
std::vector<std::string> dataLine;
boost::trim_if(buf, boost::is_any_of("\t ")); // could also use plain boost::trim
boost::split(dataLine, buf, boost::is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);
std::cout << out.size() << std::endl;
```

This question was already asked: [boost::split leaves empty tokens at the beginning and end of string - is this desired behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10437406/2128694)

Comment: I searched but was unable to find the above question. Sorry for the repost.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using [C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html). This library is much faster than Boost in my opinion.  I used to use Boost to split (aka tokenize) a line of text but found this library to be much more in line with what I want.

One of the great things about `strtk::parse` is its conversion of tokens into their final value and checking the number of elements.

you could use it as so:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

// multiple delimiters should be treated as one
if( !strtk::parse( dataLine, "\t", tokens ) )
{
    std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
}
```

--- another version

```
std::string token1;
std::string token2;
std::string token3:
float value1;
float value2;

if( !strtk::parse( dataLine, "\t", token1, token2, token3, value1, value2) )
{
     std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
     // fails if the number of elements is not what you want
}
```

Online documentation for the library:  [String Tokenizer Documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23198/C-String-Toolkit-StrTk-Tokenizer)
Link to the source code: [C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/downloads/strtk.zip)

Comment: I may consider switching to the STL in the future for my needs, but for now I have a lot of code using boost.

Comment: I have an incredible amount of code use boost as well.  I was using boost tokenizer too.  I switch this particular functionality to strtk because of the speed.  Add to the speed the added ability to convert tokens into numbers on the fly and it was a no brainer for me to switch.

Comment: @DannyK This library seemed very popular around ~2013, would you say the point still stands in 2022?

Answer (score 1):

Leading and trailing whitespace is intentionally left alone by `boost::split` because it does not know if it is significant or not. The solution is to use `boost::trim` before calling `boost::split`.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

....

boost::trim(buf);
```

Comment: Before calling it? Usually you split and then trim the tokens, right?

Comment: @Nick: That would depend. In the original question the user was splitting tab-delimited files, so trimming before was correct.