# boost::split(result, input, boost::is_any_of("(, )")) can't split empty space

Tags: c++, boost, split

code is:

```
vector<string> result;
string input = "Ellipse(50, 50, 200, 300)"
boost::split(result, input, boost::is_any_of("(, )"))

int i=0;
for (auto at=result.begin(); at != result.end(); at++)
    cout << ++i << " " << *at << endl;
```

output is:

```
1 Ellipse
2 50
3 
4 50
5 
6 200
7
8 300
9
```

I want to get just Ellipse and integers, not empty space.

How can I get correct result?

input string can't be changed.

Comment: Have a tried a backslash space in the string ? ```"(,\ )"```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the empty spaces properly: `erase_all(str1, " ");`.

Another alternative would be to use `boost::token_compress_on`:

```
boost::trim_if(input, boost::is_any_of(" "));
boost::split(result, input, boost::is_any_of("(, )"), boost::token_compress_on);
```

This question was already asked: [boost::split leaves empty tokens at the beginning and end of string - is this desired behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437406/boostsplit-leaves-empty-tokens-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-string-is-this-de)
and
[How to use boost split to split a string and ignore empty values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690389/how-to-use-boost-split-to-split-a-string-and-ignore-empty-values/15690666)

Comment: The problem is that he has two consecutive tokens, `','` and `' '`: the empty element he gets is the empty string between them. The use of `boost::token_compress_on` is actually THE solution of his problem, the other is just a workaround.